# Archivos eliminados intentan subirse a github

Tags: git, github

Me encuentro con un problema y me gustaría si pudieran ayudarme.

Pasó esto:
Estoy haciendo mi portfolio, tenía unos archivos de video, al realizar el commit y proceder a pushear los cambios a mi repositorio de github, durante el proceso me marcó un error ya que alguno de los videos eran más pesados que 50mb que al parecer es el límite de github.
A continuación con un programa comprimí los videos y les cambie el formato (de mp4 a webm), modifiqué las rutas y todo para que llamara a esos archivos.
El "pusheo" que intenté nunca sucedió, por lo que luego de hacer estos cambios que mencioné, volví a realizar otro commit e intenté hacer un nuevo push pero me sigue marcando una y otra vez, que los archivos son más pesados que lo que permite github.
Esos archivos ya no existen, pero por algún motivo siguen estando "cacheados" o algo así al momento de intentar realizar el push.

No conozco mucho de git, pero creo estar haciendolo bien, pero no consigo subir mis cambios a mi repositiorio de github.

Alguna solución?

Comment: Me acaba de pasar exactamente este mismo problema y no estoy pudiendo solucionarlo. Ya no se que hacer porque le vengo dando vueltas, y git se quedó empecinado en subir una imagen que es muy grande. La eliminé, la reemplacé por otra con el mismo nombre pero menos pesada, e intenté cuanto comando para que deje de hacer eso pero no hay caso.
Si alguien sabe me ayudaría muchísimo!

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no están "en cache". Lo que sucede es que los archivos, independientemente de lo que hayas hecho con ellos en revisions sucesivas, ya son parte de revisiones del proyecto. Al tratar de hacer `git push`, se envían todas las revisiones de las ramas que estés empujando (por lo menos, la revisiones que no estén en el remoto)... si los archivos son parte de alguna de esas revisiones, sigues con el problema. La mejor forma en la que lo podrías resolver es regresando a esa revision en la que los agregaste y tomando acciones correctivas reescribiendo la historia. Esto según el caso, se resuelve usando `git rebase -i` o incluso reescribiendo la historia del repositorio si se tratara de un caso muy grave de reescritura, pero en tu caso, si tienes una revision (la ultima de la rama) donde ya los archivos **no estén** y más nadie ha podido ver esas revisiones (porque no has podido empujar), puedes hacer esto:

```
git reset --soft revision-donde-fueron-agregados
git commit --amend # modificas la revision, y ya no van a estar
```

**Atención**: las revisiones posteriores quedan colapsadas con esta Es decir, no las vas a poder ver..... no se pierden, puedes recuperarlas si las necesitas con `git reflog`, pero ya no se van a ver en la historia de *esta* rama luego de ejecutar el paso).

Al hacer push ahora, te debería funcionar